# Renaming package and version names of Android project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an Android project created in eclipse. I want to slightly modify this(package names,etc) and make another app. I want both apps to be installed on phone. How to take care of versioning an  app name. How should I go about renaming package and project names?

Comment: "and make another app." - that sounds more like copy the project then rename the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply rename an android app you can do that by these two steps:

(1) Right-Click on your project folder in Eclipse and go to Refactor > Rename, and make sure to update references.

(2) Edit res/values/strings.xml and change the value of app_name to whatever you want to rename it to.